# Boost ASIO async call within handle functions

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm still learning how boost::asio works and hope to clarify something.

Take this example code from [here](https://github.com/ArashPartow/proxy/blob/master/tcpproxy_server.cpp):

```
  // Read from client complete, now send data to remote server
  void handle_downstream_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                              const size_t& bytes_transferred)
  {
     if (!error)
     {
        async_write(upstream_socket_,
              boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_,bytes_transferred),
              boost::bind(&bridge::handle_upstream_write,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
     }
     else
        close();
  }

  // Write to remote server complete, Async read from client
  void handle_upstream_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
     if (!error)
     {
        downstream_socket_.async_read_some(
             boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_,max_data_length),
             boost::bind(&bridge::handle_downstream_read,
                  shared_from_this(),
                  boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                  boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
     }
     else
        close();
}
```

It's part of a tcp proxy server that forwards incoming packets to the destination. Downstream read refers to reading from the client, while upstream write refers to writing to the host. The two handles call each other through async_write() and async_read_some() in a loop.

I have 2 questions:

First, if I change handle_downstream_read() so that async_write() is instead write() followed by a direct function call to handle_upstream_write(), how will this change the execution of the code? If I understand it correctly, it means that handle_downstream_read() will now be blocking io_service instead of returning instantly? But is that a problem? Shouldn't these things be executed sequentially anyways?

Second, assuming the above change is bad, what should I do if I wanted to make some changes to the content in upstream_socket_ in handle_downstream_read() before calling handle_upstream_write()? Should I call that modification function asynchronously and have that function call async_write()? Would that put the next loop of read/write into a different "thread"?

Thanks, and sorry for the wordy question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also currently learning Boost Asio, and if I understood the first part of your question correctly, I believe replacing `async_write()` with `write()` is not the right way to go, as that will block the entire thread (However, I'm not entirely sure. Maybe an expert in Boost Asio can confirm this?).

I think you might want to look into Boost Asio Coroutines as they allow you to sequence async functions such as `async_write()`. Coroutines will block execution at async functions, until that async function finishes, but only for that specific connection - NOT the entire thread.

Some examples with Boost Asio Coroutines can be found here https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp17_examples.html

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, and keep in mind that I'm a beginner when it comes to Boost Asio, so my answer could be completely wrong. Hopefully someone with more experience can answer your question better.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm looking at Coroutines code examples now and understand it as a sort of mutex-ish mechanic that you pass around? I think this will work and will keep reading, but my issue should be much simpler and not require any new boost features to implement.

Do you know if I can just call std::async to execute some code in a separate thread (not with io_service), and then have that function call async_write/read_some when it's done, which guarantees execution in the io_service thread again?

Comment: That's a bit too advanced for me, so I can't really answer your question. It does seem like it would work, but I'm not sure how Boost Asio would handle something like that.

Comment: No problem, thanks anyways! I'm going to give it a try in my code and see if it turns out alright.